# Creating a minimum heap using the Comparable interface

Tags: java, heap, comparable

I am having an issue with adding my string to create a minimum heap. When I debug my code I believe that I am having an issue when adding 'B', however I run into an infinite loop that prints out null.

Here is my string:

```
    String[] s = {"D", "F", "I", "C", "H", "A", "E", "J", "B", "G"};
```

Add method:

```
public void add(Comparable newEntry) {
    int newIndex = ++lastIndex;
    int parentIndex = newIndex / 2;
    while ((newIndex > 1) && newEntry.compareTo(heap[parentIndex]) < 0) {
        heap[newIndex] = heap[parentIndex];
        newIndex = parentIndex;
        parentIndex = newIndex / 2;
    } // end while
    heap[newIndex] = newEntry;
} // end add
```

And my constructor:

```
public MinHeap() {
        heap = new Comparable[DEFAULT_MAX_SIZE];
        lastIndex = 0;
    } // end default constructor
    public MinHeap(int maxSize) {
        heap = new Comparable[maxSize];
        lastIndex = 0;
    } // end constructor
    public MinHeap(Comparable[] entries) {
        lastIndex = entries.length;
        heap = new Comparable[lastIndex + 1];
        // copy given array to data field
        for (int index = 0; index < entries.length; index++)
            heap[index+1] = entries[index];
        // create heap
        for (int index = heap.length/2; index > 0; index--)
            reheap(index);
    } // end constructor
```

Driver for my code:

```
public class MinHeapDriver {
    public static void main(String[] argv)  {
      MinHeap aHeap = createMinHeap();
      testMinHeapOperations(aHeap);
    }  // end main   

   public static MinHeap createMinHeap() {
        MinHeap aHeap = new MinHeap();  
      String[] s = {"D", "F", "I", "C", "H", "A", "E", "J", "B", "G"};
        System.out.println("Testing add()");
      for (int i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
         System.out.print(s[i] + " ");
         aHeap.add(s[i]);
      }
      aHeap.display();
      return aHeap;
   } // creatMinHeap
```

Comment: Since there is no print statement anywhere in the shown code, I don't see how an infinite loop can prints out null.

Comment: Edited to include my java driver

Comment: So where is the infinite loop? Is it somewhere inside `display()`? Or it is because `removeMin()` doesn't work right? In either case, how did you expect to get help for those?

Comment: I am solely speaking about the add method

Comment: Well, the loop in the `add` method doesn't contain a print statement, so it simply **cannot** both loop infinitely *and* print a null. To print something, it would have to exit the loop so the caller can print something, ergo there is no infinite loop *in* the `add` method. And the loop in the driver that calls `add` is a normal `for` loop, so it will loop exactly 10 times, also not an infinite loop.

Comment: as always a [mcve] would help: we just can guess what all the variables are, and, more relevant, what is in method `display`....on the other hand we do not need to see the constructors that are not being used

Comment: posted code is almost running fina (using my simple `display()` and empty `testMinHeapOperations()`), no infinite loop : `Testing add()` 
`D F I C H A E J B G `, 
`[null, A, B, C, D, G, I, E, J, F, H, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `add` method. The problem is in your `display` method.

You have created a heap in which the root node is at index 1 in the array. The output of your `display` method indicates that the array is:

```
[null, A, B, C, D, G, I, E, J, F, H, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

If we ignore the 0 element (which you chose not to use), that corresponds to this heap:

```
             A
        B         C
     D     G   I     E
    J F   H
```

That is a valid min-heap.

My suggestion is that you change your code so that the heap starts at index 0, rather than index 1. That will save you a lot of confusion. All you have to do is change the parent and child calculations. Parent of a node at index `x` will be at `(x-1)/2`. Left child of the node at index `x` is `(2*x)+1`, and right child is at `(2*x)+2`. And when you add a node, you add it to `a[lastIndex]` before incrementing `lastIndex`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the conceptualization was really a big issue of mine.